# How to align two components (checkbox & label) in datagrid column using custom itemrenderer

Tags: itemrenderer

I am working on one application where i need to align checkbox & label in one datagrid coloumn. I have created custom item renderer with checkbox & label. Below is my code for custom itemrenderer,

As of now it is not showing proper alignment. Can anyone suggest any input on same.

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" clipAndEnableScrolling="true">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            override public function prepare(hasBeenRecycled:Boolean):void {
                lblData.text = data[column.dataField]
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:HGroup verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center">
        <s:CheckBox id="myCheckBox" selected="false"/>
        <s:Label id="lblData" text="{data.FirstName}"/>
    </s:HGroup>
</s:GridItemRenderer> `
```

Comment: Hello , I have fixed it by adding top & left properties to HGroup tag. Thanks anyways..